# Retrieving object from a manytomany field

Tags: django, django-orm

I am still trying to wrap my head around the ORM. I am trying to set this up so that a user can follow many networks. I set the modal up as a many to many field. Now when a user writes a post he can pick from one of the "networks" he follows to post it to. How would I return all the networks the user follows? I'm looking through the documentation but it just isn't clicking. The model is below and I am using the Django authentication.

```
class SubNetwork(models.Model):
    sub_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sub_name

    def number_of_followers(self):
        self.number = self.followers.count()
        return self.number

    def number_of_posts(self):
        self.total_posts = self.fishingreport_set.count()
        return self.total_posts
```

Comment: If you don't specify a `related_name`, the default should be `user.subnetwork_set.all()`.

Comment: Thank you. I see the mistake I was making now.